# pandas inner join performance issue

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv file and I load them into pandas data frame. One file is large, about 10M rows and 20 columns (all string type) and size is around 1G bytes, the other file is small, about 5k rows, and 5 columns and size is around 1M. I want to do inner join by a single common column between the two data frame.

This is how I join,

```
mergedDataSet = pd.merge(smallDataFrame, largeDataFrame, on='uid', how='inner')
```

I tried if I sample 1% of the big data set, program runs smoothly without any issues and complete within 5 seconds, so I verified function should be ok for my code.

But if I join the real large data set, the program will be terminated in about 20-30 seconds, error message is `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`. I am using Python 2.7 with miniconda, on Mac OSX and I run from PyCharm. My machine has 16G memory and well above the size of 1G file.

Wondering if any thoughts to tune performance of data frame join in pandas, or any other quick solution for inner join?

Another confusion from me is, why the program is KILLed? By whom and why reason?

**Edit 1**, error captured in /var/log/system.log when doing inner join,

```
Aug 27 11:00:18 foo-laptop com.apple.CDScheduler[702]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
Aug 27 11:00:18 foo-laptop com.apple.CDScheduler[47]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0
Aug 27 11:00:33 foo-laptop iTerm2[43018]: Time to encode state for window <PseudoTerminal: 0x7fb3659d3960 tabs=1 window=<PTYWindow: 0x7fb3637c0c80 frame=NSRect: {{0, 0}, {1280, 800}} title=5. tail alpha=1.000000 isMain=1 isKey=1 isVisible=1 delegate=0x7fb3659d3960>>: 0.02136099338531494
Aug 27 11:00:41 foo-laptop iTerm2[43018]: Time to encode state for window <PseudoTerminal: 0x7fb3659d3960 tabs=1 window=<PTYWindow: 0x7fb3637c0c80 frame=NSRect: {{0, 0}, {1280, 800}} title=5. tail alpha=1.000000 isMain=0 isKey=0 isVisible=1 delegate=0x7fb3659d3960>>: 0.01138699054718018
Aug 27 11:00:46 foo-laptop kernel[0]: low swap: killing pid 92118 (python2.7)
Aug 27 11:00:46 foo-laptop kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 789 [CallHistoryPlugi]
Aug 27 11:00:56 foo-laptop iTerm2[43018]: Time to encode state for window <PseudoTerminal: 0x7fb3659d3960 tabs=1 window=<PTYWindow: 0x7fb3637c0c80 frame=NSRect: {{0, 0}, {1280, 800}} title=5. tail alpha=1.000000 isMain=0 isKey=0 isVisible=1 delegate=0x7fb3659d3960>>: 0.01823097467422485
Aug 27 11:00:58 foo-laptop kernel[0]: process WeChat[85077] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 184; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 2193951
Aug 27 11:00:58 foo-laptop com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash[92123]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
Aug 27 11:00:58 foo-laptop ReportCrash[92123]: Invoking spindump for pid=85077 wakeups_rate=184 duration=245 because of excessive wakeups
Aug 27 11:01:03 foo-laptop com.apple.CDScheduler[702]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
Aug 27 11:01:03 foo-laptop com.apple.CDScheduler[47]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Perhaps values in column 'uid' are many-to-many, say for value 1 you get 100 records in frame 1 and 10 in frame 2, so join yields 1000 records. And may be what happens is that your frame grows so big that does not fit into memory or eats all resources.

Comment: I agree with @AndreyVykhodtsev - if you have duplicates in `uid` column - they will be multiplied in the merged DF (for example if you have 3x `uid`s with value `1` in one DF and 2x `uid`s with value `1` in the second DF - you'll have __6 rows__ with `uid==1` in the merged DF). Most probably your Python process gets killed by the OOM (Out Of Memory) Killer - check in the `/var/log/system.log` (`/var/log/messages`)

Comment: @MaxU, thanks for the advice and I have captured the error in `/var/log/system.log` and post the error in Edit 1 section of my post. Looks like it is killed by the system. Wondering if there is any way to check duplicate value or cardinality for a specific column like `uid` in `pandas` `DataFrame`?

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev, thanks for the advice and good hint. Wondering if there is any way to check duplicate value or cardinality for a specific column like `uid` in `pandas` `DataFrame`?

Comment: Yes, just check df['uid'].value_counts() on both sides. or df1[df1.uid.isin(df2.uid.unique())]['uid'].value_counts()

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev, it seems your guess is correct. Would you mind to add a reply, so that I can mark it as answer to benefit other people? BTW, could you explain what does this statement mean `df1[df1.uid.isin(df2.uid.unique())]['uid'].value_counts()`, confused by `isin(df2.uid.unique())]` part.

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev, i agree with Lin Ma - it might help others in future if you would post it as an answer (ideally with a small example) ;)

Comment: Well I decided to not to post it as an answer as the question seemed to be "Another confusion from me is, why the program is KILLed? By whom and why reason?" - I don't know the answer to that. I will post it as an answer

Comment: @LinMa isin(df2.uid.unique())] just checks that df1.uid has the values that are present in df2.uid

Comment: @MaxU, :) I think Andrey is better. He is more expert. :)

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev, from the system log, it seems killed by Mac OSX?  Are you using Mac or other OS?

Comment: @AndreyVykhodtsev, still a bit lost by this statement `df1.uid.isin(df2.uid.unique())`, my confusion is, I think `df2.uid.unique()` will get a list of unique `uid` in `df2`, but `df1.uid` will also return a list of all `uid` of `df1`, so you check a list (`uid` of `df1`) in another list (`df2.uid.unique()`)? How does it work internally to check a list in another list? I thought your original idea is to check if a `uid` in `df1` exists in `df2`, if so, get # of total such `uid`s in `df1`?

Comment: @LinMa, well I think this piece of doc should solve your confusion : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html

Comment: Thanks @AndreyVykhodtsev for the reference, so it seems `isin` is operation to compare two lists, and it will complete compare if any element on the first list is in the 2nd list?

Comment: Hi @LinMa, df1.uid.isin(df2.uid.unique) returns boolean vector (true/false), containing true if this value is contained in df2.uid and False if it is not. This vector is then used to index df1 - we get only these values that are present in df2. Then we do value_counts() and see which ones have cardinality > 1

Comment: Thanks @AndreyVykhodtsev, it is very smart! Vote up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the cardinality of 'uid' column on both sides. It is most probable that your join is multiplying the data manyfold. For example, if you have uid with value 1 in 100 records of dataframe1 and in 10 records in dataframe2, your join would yield 1000 records.

to check the cardinality, I would do the following:

```
df1[df1.uid.isin(df2.uid.unique())]['uid'].value_counts()
df2[df2.uid.isin(df1.uid.unique())]['uid'].value_counts()
```

This code will check if the values of 'uid' that are present in other frame's uid and have duplicates.